# Guardar lista de datos en un solo campo MySQL con Node

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, api, express

Hoy vengo a exponer un problema con el cual espero que me puedan ayudar. Estoy empezando con node js, y trato de hacer un sistema de ventas para poner en practica lo que voy aprendiendo. No uso dependencias de mas porque quiero aprender lo basico y el como y porque de la cosas para luego probar mas. Tengo una api con node y express. Utilizo al dependencia mysql para conectar a una bd de este tipo y express-myconnection para gestionar las conexiones. No estoy usando MVC y no renderizo ninguna pagina porque solo necesito los json que consultare con React luego.

Tengo una tabla factura y una de productos que se relacionan a traves de una tabla de detalles donde se guardaran los productos vendidos. Mi duda es lo siguiente. Como puedo enviar una lista de productos a la tabla detalles??

Les dejo mi codigo por aca que por el momento solo me permite guardar un producto por venta. Recuerden que mi codigo no es tan sofisticado porque estoy aprendiendo y mi objetivo es aprender el porque y el como por ahora. La aplicacion la estoy testeando con postman y me da un error de sintaxis:

"code": "ER_PARSE_ERROR",
"errno": 1064,
"sqlMessage": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '29, 30, cantidad = 5,\n                    precio = 31, porcentaje = 15' at line 1",
"sqlState": "42000",
"index": 0,
"sql": "Insert into Factura_Detalle set id_factura = 94881, id_producto = 27, 29, 30, cantidad = 5,\n                    precio = 31, porcentaje = 15"

### Agradezco de antemano el apoyo. Espero puedan ayudarme.

```
//Agregar nueva Venta
router.post('/add', (req, res)=>{
    const sql = 'Insert into Factura set ?';   

    let id_usuario =  req.body.id_usuario;
    let id_cliente = req.body.id_cliente;
    let monto = req.body.monto;
    let credito = req.body.credito;
    let nruc = req.body.nruc;
    let nombre_cliente = req.body.nombre_cliente;
    let fecha_venc = req.body.fecha_venc;
    let iva = req.body.iva;
    let num_factura = req.body.num_factura;
    let anulada = req.body.anulada;
    let tcambio = req.body.tcambio;
        
    let cantidad =  req.body.cantidad;
    let precio = req.body.precio;
    let porcentaje = req.body.porcentaje;
    
            const factura = {
                id_usuario, 
                id_cliente,
                fecha: new Date(),   
                monto,
                credito,
                nruc,
                nombre_cliente,
                fecha_venc,
                iva,    
                num_factura,
                anulada,
                tcambio 
            }
 
    req.getConnection((err, conn) => {
        if(err){   
            return res.send(err)
        }
        else{ 
            conn.query(sql, factura, (error, result) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    return 
                }
                else{
                    console.log("Factura guardada");
                    const idfac = result.insertId;
                                        
                    const sql2 = `Insert into Factura_Detalle set id_factura = ?, id_producto = ?, cantidad = ?,
                    precio = ?, porcentaje = ?`;
                    // const sql2 = 'Insert into Factura_Detalle set ?';
                    conn.query(sql2, [idfac, [...id_producto], cantidad, precio, porcentaje], (error, rows) => {
                        if (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                            res.send(error) 
                            return  
                        }
                        else{
                            console.log("Detalles guardados");
                            
                            const sql3 = `Update Producto set stock= stock-${cantidad} 
                            where id_producto= ${id_producto}`;
                            conn.query(sql3, [cantidad, id_producto], (error) =>{
                                if (error) {  
                                    console.log(error);
                                    return 
                                }
                                else{
                                    res.send('Venta Exitosa');
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }  
            })
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Si estoy entendiendo bien, estás tratando de insertar varios productos a la vez por medio de `Insert into Factura_Detalle set id_factura = ?, id_producto = ?, cantidad = ?, precio = ?, porcentaje = ?` y entonces el problema de sintaxis te dice: "...  id_producto = 27, 29, 30...". La causa del error es que la sintaxis de "INSERT SET" solamente funciona para agregar una fila a la vez. Tal vez quieras probar cambiar el "INSERT SET" por la sintaxis de "INSERT VALUES ()"

Comment: Hola Eduardo. Gracias por la pronta respuesta. No sabia lo que comentas, gracias por eso, pero estuve probando algunas alternativas conforme a eso y no funciona. Probe con: 
const sql2 = `INSERT INTO factura_detalle(id_factura_detalle, id_factura, id_producto, cantidad, precio, porcentaje) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)`;
Da el siguiente error:
"code": "ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW", "errno": 1136, "sqlMes": "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1", "sql": "INSERT INTO factura_detalle(id_factura_detalle, id_factura, id_producto, cantidad, precio, porcentaje) VALUES (94885,27, 29, 30,5,31,15)"

Comment: y con esta: 
const sql2 = `INSERT INTO factura_detalle(id_factura_detalle, id_factura, id_producto, cantidad, precio, porcentaje) VALUES (?,(?),?,?,?)`;
Da este error:

    "code": "ER_OPERAND_COLUMNS",
    "errno": 1241,
    "sqlMessage": "Operand should contain 1 column(s)",
    "sql": "INSERT INTO factura_detalle(id_factura_detalle, id_factura, id_producto, cantidad, precio, porcentaje)                     
 VALUES (94886,(27, 29, 30),5,31,15)"
Parece que no es la forma correcta asi pero que se hace en estos casos? en las ventas el producto, cantidad y precio deben ser multiples

Comment: Ya veo. Me parece que en tus tablas tiene que haber un registro en "factura_detalle" por cada producto que relaciones con la factura. Tu query para hacer el "insert" al final de todo el proceso de sustitución debería lucir algo como: 

INSERT INTO factura_detalle(id_factura_detalle, id_factura, id_producto, cantidad, precio, porcentaje) VALUES(94886,27,5,31,15), VALUES(94886,29,5,31,15), VALUES(94886,30,5,31,15).

O sea, que tienes que agregar un juego de valores en VALUES por cada producto que quieras relacionar a una factura.

Tal vez con esta idea puedas continuar :)

Comment: Gracias por tu apoyo Eduardo. Gracias a tus respuestas me diste nuevas ideas y pude revisar otras fuentes que me ayudaron a resolver mi problema. No se si sea la forma correcta, se que esta se puede mejorar (quizas usar promesas o async-await) pero creo que la logica si es esta. La pondre a continuación como respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

A veces cuando eres novato creo que tratamos de ver las cosas por encima y queremos dar solucion a un problema atacandolo directamente pero a veces falta saber mas sobre las tecnologias que usamos. Creo que este fue el caso, solo queria meter un conjunto de datos en un solo campo de mi tabla en la BD. Pero segun esta fuente:
https://www.delftstack.com/es/howto/mysql/store-array-in-mysql/

Pude aclararme algunas cosas sobre las bases de datos relacionales. Tambien agradezco los comentarios de Eduardo Hernández que me estuvo ayudando en el proceso. Quizas alguien pueda mejorarlo o hacerlo mas correcto. Lo dejé comentado el código para que otro novato como yo o aun mas, pueda entenderlo.

```
//Agregar nueva Venta
router.post('/add', (req, res)=>{
    //Creo un objeto con cada uno de los valores que agregaré a la tabla factura.
    //Esta tendra un identificador unico
    const factura = {
        id_usuario: req.body.id_usuario,//cada valor del objeto viene como  
        id_cliente: req.body.id_cliente,//parametro que enviamos desde el front 
        fecha: new Date(),   
        monto: req.body.monto,
        credito: req.body.credito,
        nruc: req.body.nruc,
        nombre_cliente: req.body.nombre_cliente,
        fecha_venc: req.body.fecha_venc,
        iva: req.body.iva,    
        num_factura: req.body.num_factura,
        anulada: req.body.anulada,
        tcambio: req.body.tcambio
    }
    //Creo variables separadas para los datos que irán en el detalle
    //Se insertará un nuevo detalle en base a la cantidad de productos a vender
    //Todos los detalles estarán asociados a una misma Factura. 
    let id_producto = Object.values(req.body.id_producto);
    let cantidad =  Object.values(req.body.cantidad);//Object.values --> Nos sirve para tomar los valores de un objeto 
    let precio = Object.values(req.body.precio);//y convertirlos en un arreglo. Ya que los datos enviados se mandan se reconocen como objeto
    let porcentaje = req.body.porcentaje;
    
    req.getConnection((err, conn) => {//Enviamos la peticion
        const sql = 'Insert into Factura set ?';
        if(err){   
            return res.send(err)
        }
        else{ 
            conn.query(sql, factura, (error, result) => {//Enviamos la consulta. Guardamos la factura. El 2do parametro es la respuesta
                //Si hay un error entra aca y sale de la funcion
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    return 
                }
                else{
                    // Si no es porque los datos en la factura se ingresaron
                    console.log("Factura guardada");
                    //capturamos el Id de la factura que acaba de guardarse. Accediendo al objeto de la respuesta
                    const idfac = result.insertId;

                    const sql2 = `INSERT INTO factura_detalle(id_factura, id_producto, cantidad, precio, porcentaje)
                    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)`;
                    const sql3 = `Update Producto set stock=stock- ? where id_producto= ?`;
                //Tomamos de referencia el arreglo (lista de productos) enviado y lo recorremos con un bucle for in
                 for (index in id_producto){
                    //por cada vuelta de bucle ingresamos el producto, cantidad y precio desde la posicion 0 del arreglo hasta la ultima.
                    conn.query(sql2, [idfac, id_producto[index], cantidad[index], precio[index], porcentaje], (error) => {
                        if (error) {
                            console.log(error);   
                        }
                        else{
                            console.log("Detalles guardados");                           
                        }
                    });
                 }//fin for in
                //Luego declaramos otro bucle que hará las actualizaciones sobre el stock de productos
                 for (const key in id_producto) {
                     //de igual forma esta vez tomamos de referencia la cantidad que se ira restando al stock
                     // de cada producto por cada vuelta            
                    conn.query(sql3, [cantidad[key], id_producto[key]], (er) =>{
                        if (er) {  
                            console.log(er);
                            return 
                        }
                        else{
                            console.log("producto actualizado");  
                        }
                    });//fin ultima query   
                 }//fin for in 

                }//Fin else si se guardan detalles a la factura  
            })
          
        }//Fin else si se guarda factura 
    
    });//Fin conexion

});//Fin petición
```